# My coworkers get more pay than me, even though I have been longer at my workplace

Tags: work-environment, teamwork, bonus, coworking, law

My coworkers earn around 30-40k more than I do. We do the same work, in fact I usually perform better than them and have been with the company longer. It does not seem fair. I don't feel comfortable raising this with my manager as we are not that friendly.

Is it better to leave my current position and join a new company for a better salary and more appreciation, or would it be best to stay and talk with my manager about my situation (even though I doubt it would make a difference).

Also, my bonus was deducted to pay some of my other co workers, which is also unfair. The company announced a 100% bonus, but some of my coworkers and myself were given about 90% while other colleagues (that my manager favors) were given an extra bonus. Can I sue the management for doing this, since the email mentions 100% bonus. Will it be wise to do this or to let it go?

Comment: You're asking two questions that's not going to work out, especially since the last question ( about lawsuit) is off topic for this site. You talk to lawyers about law, not randoms on the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid

Comment: "Should I stay or leave" is also off topic, since that's a judgement call we can't make for you
 But the answer is that you can and should talk to your manager. This isn't about being friends, this is about business. Ask (don't complain) what the company needs to see from you to give you a raise... And stop looking at co-workers' salaries, that's completely irrelevant to getting the company to value you more highly.

Comment: You are in a position you cannot talk about pay with your manager?

Comment: This community will never grow, if you keep putting posts on hold.

Comment: @Sidius: Take that to Meta, please. (And review what's already been said there about how SE differs from other communities.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on if you want to stay at the company. Changing jobs can be a pain.

If you have solid information that other employees with similar job description are making significantly more than you, and it is a believable pay level for your profession, then ask for that pay. Don't bring rivalries into it ("I heard Jill makes more than me, and I want the same as her."). Schedule a time (do you have an annual performance review coming up?) and make your case. Highlight your successes, emphasize your good qualities, and mention projects that you have completed successfully -- especially if they increased revenue or decreased expenses. For example:

"There's something I'd like to talk to you about. I've been with the company for X years and have always received favorable performance reviews. I work hard and bring good value to the company. I am very proficient at my job. Two years ago I completed a project that streamlined our X process, on time, making sales go 20% faster. Also, I updated all of the old [file type] records in only 3 months. I have done some research, and I believe that for someone with my skill set, experience and proven work ethic, an appropriate salary would be $$$."  Then stop talking and let him respond.

After addressing that issue, you can also bring up the bonus issue if you want. Have the emails printed out and ready. "Also, last year we were promised a 100% bonus, but I only received a 90% bonus. I'd like to know why I didn't receive the bonus I was promised."

Depending on his response, decide if the job is worth it. If not, start looking.

Comment: very convincing indeed. might give it a shot, thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have raised the issue of pay with management - without any result. That must mean they don't acknowledge or value your results or they believe they can get away with paying you less.

In general, it is difficult to ever overcome starting at a lower wage - so if pay is your number one priority at the moment, it seems your only option is moving on.

Regarding the lawsuit, the risk/reward ratio seems unfavorable to you.